# how to remove blank space for bar charts

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have 2 bar charts, and the chart will visible based on the parameter. I made the hidden property true for both chart based on parameter's value. But I am not able to remove the blank space for the hidden chart. Could any one please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd make sure that the graphs aren't inside a Rectangle object. I'd also see if the report option for "Consume White Space" could fix this. Try switching their positions or moving them around. Formatting within SSRS is very delicate, so it may just take some slight tweaking.